# Change wishlist url in magento

Tags: magento

I have a special request.
It is possible to point the whole wishlist links to something different?
Everything should be replaced with a different name. 
So instead of demo.store.com/wishlist to be demo.store.com/scrapbook
Where should I start to look, if it's possible at all?

Answer (score 3):

You can add this to `app/etc/local.xml`:

```
<config>
    <!-- other stuff -->
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <wishlist>
                <args>
                    <frontName>scrapbook</frontName>
                </args>
            </wishlist>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
    <!-- other stuff -->
</config>
```

Comment: Do you know if this will modification will change everywhere where is a reference to wishlist? because there are many. add to wishlist, view wishlist. .etc.

Comment: Yes, this is the point of frontNames. As long as the URL is generated with the URL model the value will be changed appropriately. See *app/etc/local.xml* - this is already technically taking place for the adminhtml module ;-)