# Customer account url rewrite

Tags: magento, e-commerce

Im new to Magento. Whats the best way of going about having the customer account URL show from
http://www.mydomain.com/customer/account/

to

http://www.mydomain.com/customer or /register if I want people to register?

Answer (score 1):

You could try creating a custom module with

```
<global>
  <rewrite>
    <mynamespace_mymodule_customer>
        <from><![CDATA[#^/customer#]]></from>
        <to>/customer/account</to>
        <complete>1</complete>
    </mynamespace_mymodule_customer>
    <mynamespace_mymodule_register>
        <from><![CDATA[#^/register#]]></from>
        <to>/customer/register</to>
        <complete>1</complete>
    </mynamespace_mymodule_register>
     </rewrite>
</global>
```

see [Custom URL for Magento's basket page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12722841/custom-url-for-magentos-basket-page)